# Trouble switching accounts on teams devices

Tags: microsoft-office-365, licensing, office365, microsoft-teams

Because user licensing for teams devices is deprecated, I need to switch to an Office 365 resource account, licensed with Microsoft Teams Rooms Basic. I've created a resource called 'Teams Meeting Room', with the email address `teams.room@example.com`. I've logged in to the device with the Teams Meeting Room account, and I've edited the setting for the device in the Microsoft Teams Admin Center, but Teams Rooms on Windows still shows the original user with its Office 365 E3 license.

#### In Microsoft 365 admin center

##### Users -> Active Users:

```
Display name : Sales Team
Username : salesteam@example.com
Licenses: Office 365 E3
```

##### Resources -> Rooms & Equipment:

```
Name  : Teams Meeting Room
Email : teams.room@example.com
Type  : Equipment
```

##### Licenses:

```
License Name      : Microsoft Teams Rooms Basic
Assigned to name  : Teams Meeting Room
Assigned to email : teams.room@example.com
```

#### In Microsoft Teams Admin Center > Teams Devices

##### Teams Rooms on Windows

```
Display name   : Sales Team
Username       : salesteam@example.com
Device name    : logitech-tap XXXXXXXXXXXX
License        : **Office 365 E3**
Host name      : DESKTOP-XXXXXXX
Health status  : Healthy
Manufacturer   : logitech
Model          : tap
Tags           : --
Offline since  : --
Usage status   : Idle
History        : View
```

##### Edit Settings:

```
Name: Sales Team (logitech-tap XXXXXXXXXXXX)
Email                  : teams.room@example.com
Supported meeting mode : Modern authentication  : On
Exchange address       : teams.room@example.com
```

#### On device `DESKTOP-XXXXXXX`

When I go to `DESKTOP-XXXXXXX` and go to teams configuration, I'm prompted for the administrator password, then I can set up the login user. I have this set as `teams.room@example.com`.

When I complete the configuration, it shows the license as valid, but when a meeting is started on the device, the display name still shows 'Sales Team', and Microsoft Teams Admin Center > Teams Devices still shows username: `salesteam@example.com` and License: `Office 365 E3`.

I feel like I've run out of places to configure -- the settings for the device in Teams Admin Center and the device both point to `teams.room@example.com` but that's not what's showing on the front page of Teams Admin Center > Teams Devices.

What am I missing?

Comment: `1.` How long ago have you made these changes? It can take time for changes to "propagate" through the Office 365 platform and between different services in the platform. `2.` Open a support case in your Office 365 tenant. It's free. They'll help you resolve this.

Comment: The changes were made last week. I expect things to take up to a couple of hours to propagate, but 5 calendar days is a bit much. Will try a microsoft support case.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, the process of transitioning to an Office 365 resource account licensed with Microsoft Teams Rooms Basic appears to be on the right track, but there seems to be a lingering issue with the device's display name and license. To address this concern comprehensively, it's crucial to consider a few key factors and potentially employ some useful code.

Firstly, it's possible that the device has not fully registered with the new resource account, resulting in the continued display of the original user's information with an Office 365 E3 license in the Teams Admin Center. To rectify this, you can try restarting the device and verifying its network connection:

```
# Restart the device using PowerShell
Restart-Computer -ComputerName "DESKTOP-XXXXXXX"
```

Additionally, allow some time for the device to sync with the Teams service. If these steps don't yield the desired results, a manual registration through PowerShell can be attempted, where you'd use the "Register-AzureADDevice" command with the device's ID and the resource account's object ID:

```
# Manually register the device with PowerShell
Register-AzureADDevice -DeviceId <device ID> -ObjectId <resource account object ID>
```

Furthermore, it's important to ensure that the device is running the latest version of Teams Rooms. You can use the Teams Admin Center to verify and update the device:

```
# Update the device's software to the latest version
Update-TeamsRoomDevice -Identity "DESKTOP-XXXXXXX"
```

Double-check that the device has been correctly assigned a Teams Rooms Basic license, and ensure that the device is signed in with the correct resource account:

```
# Check the device's licensing status
Get-AzureADDevice -ObjectId <device ID>
```

```
# Verify the device's sign-in account
Get-AzureADDevice -ObjectId <device ID>
```